# Send window messages to drag treeview item to other process

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, message-queue, ui-automation, data-objects

I can enumerate the treeview items within a window in another process. I'd like to be able to programmatically initiate a drag-drop operation on nodes in the treeview, dragging the item into a window that I control. Ultimately, I just want to access the `DataObject` of each treeview item.

Is it possible to use `PostMessage`, or some other method, to initiate and complete the drag-drop sequence? Can it be done without taking ownership of the mouse (i.e without interruption to the user's mouse position)?

Is it possible to complete the same task, even if the treeview item is in a collapsed treeview folder (*without* expanding the folder)?

Comment: but tree-view not implement drag-drop. and not create any `IDataObject` it simply notify parent window that user want to drag - `TVN_BEGINDRAG` but all drag drop must be custom implemented - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298388(v=vs.85).aspx. what is your real goal ?

Comment: real goal: *Ultimately, I just want to access the DataObject of each treeview item.*

Comment: but what you understand under `DataObject of each treeview item` ? tree view not implement this

Comment: There is no `IDataObject` of each tree node, unless the owning app creates one during an *active* drag operation.

Comment: Ultimately, I just want to access the **IDataObject that each treeview item exposes in a drag operation**.

Comment: why you decide that treeview **implement** drag-drop , including `IDataObject` implementation ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080724-00/?p=21483

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: This is not applicable. If you believe otherwise, please expand on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `IDataObject` in the TreeView itself.

It is the responsibility of the TreeView's owning application to detect when the user is trying to drag a TreeView node (the TreeView notifies the application via [`TNV_BEGINDRAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773504.aspx)), at which time the app can then create a suitable `IDataObject` and pass it to the [`DoDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486.aspx) function to start an OLE drag operation, which can pass data across process boundaries.

There are no window messages you can send to the TreeView (or the app) to retrieve an `IDataObject` for a tree node, or to start a drag operation directly.  About the only thing you can do on your end is to either:

1. [simulate mouse input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) over the TreeView itself, so it thinks the user is dragging a node normally.
2. simulate `TVN_BEGINDRAG` manually.  This requires using [`VirtualAllocEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890.aspx) and [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx) to allocate and fill a suitable [`NMTREEVIEW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773411.aspx) structure inside of the memory address space of the TreeView's owning process, and then send `TVN_BEGINDRAG` to the TreeView's parent window, pointing it to that `NMTREEVIEW` struct.  Which means first using things like [`TVM_HITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773732.aspx) and [`TVM_GETITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773596.aspx) to retrieve some information that `TVN_BEGINDRAG` needs to report to the app (most notably, the tree nodes's `HTREEITEM` handle and `LPARAM` value).

This would trick the owning app into thinking the *user* is trying to drag a tree node around and act accordingly.  But, it is still going through the motions of starting a real OLE drag operation, so the user will have to then move the mouse over your app window and release the mouse button (or you will have to simulate mouse input to do it programming) so the `IDataObject` is dropped onto your window normally.

Comment: Thanks for that. If the Treeview is in the same process, but I don't control it, does option 2 get simpler? Could it be used to drag a node inside a collapsed parent node (without first expanding the parent node)?

Comment: @ThunderFrame option 2 becomes simpler only in that memory does not need to be allocated with `VirtualAllocEx()` and read/written with `(Read/Write)ProcessMemory()`, that's all. Whether or not a non-visual node can be "dragged" depends on the implementation of the TreeView owner.